# Yield inside .then function of promise response throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

Following code is throwing error:

```
  syncData().then((x) => yield put(loginUserSuccess(responseData)));
```

Error: The keyword 'yield' is reserved.

Sync data handles asynchronous operations of fetching data.I want to use yield put(provided by sagas.js) to trigger the action login user success after sync data has been performed.

Core of syncData function is as follows:

```
  export default async function syncData(dataType) {
      await Promise.all([syncData1(), syncData2()]);
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try separating it like this, using the `call` effect and then the `put` effect:

```
try {
  const res = yield call(syncData) 

  yield put(loginUserSuccess(res))

} catch(e) {

  yield put(loginUserFail(e))

}
```

Comment: I get another error: uncaught at check call: argument [object Object] is not a function

Comment: sorry, I should pass `syncData` not `syncData()`. My variables are a bit complicated so I made mistake and pass in the function call itself